# Map does not display

Tags: python, json, geojson, folium, choropleth

New to Python geo mapping. I am trying a folium template with my own data. Without Choropleth definition map displays correct. Adding Choropleth def. results in an empty map/space.

I checked numerous other empty map questions but could not trace the error. Is it something with geojson column name? How can I check if this column reference is correct?

```
import pandas as pd
import folium

state_geo = r'C:\Users\600039256\Documents\test1\Gemeentegrenzen_2018.json'
opps = r'C:\Users\600039256\Documents\test1\geotest.csv'
state_data = pd.read_csv(opps)

m = folium.Map(location=[52, 5], zoom_start=7)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=state_data,
    columns=['code', 'sales'],
    key_on='feature.properties.code',
    fill_color='YlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Opportunities'
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

Out: <folium.map.LayerControl at 0x1e46c5d14e0>

m
```

This is the Json header:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Gemeentegrenzen_2018",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1, "code": "GM0847", "gemeentena": "Someren", "Shape__Are": 0, "Shape__Len": 0, "SHAPE_Leng": 41763.7298094, "InPoly_FID": 1, "SimPgnFlag": 0, "MaxSimpTol": 5, "MinSimpTol": 5, "Shape__A_1": 0.010523453973949, "Shape__L_1": 0.45095115579216 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":
```

This is what the csv looks like:

```
stad,sales,code
Aalsmeer,194322,GM0358
Aalst,25000,GM0297
Aalten,20000,GM0197
Alkmaar,260000,GM0361
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *empty map/space*? Could you please provide the output you get?

Comment: I get an empty canvas with the size of the map, the placeholder of the map is plain white. (using jupyter). Thx for helping out!

Comment: Is there any chance you could make the json file available? It is quite difficult to check your code (and potential errors/typos) without it.

Comment: This link will hopefully work: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgZZCUSTOJ94zHttnxUDunlg8TqE

Comment: Got it. You can remove the link if you want.

Comment: Where did you find that json file? I am reasonably sure there is some sort of typo in it.

Comment: It was a shapefile converted with mapshaper.org. I included *.dbf, prj, shp, shx, cpg files. Can you identify the error? I will try another conversion tool. Thx!

Comment: I tried a conversion with Ogre, same result, empty map. The shapefile is OK, I have used it before with Geopandas, no problems.

Comment: Run this command on a shell: `sed -e '10,298d' Gemeentegrenzen_2018.json > foo.json`, then run your python code using `foo.json` in place of `Gemeentegrenzen_2018.json`. Do you get a map?

Comment: I tried this in ipython and python console, but i get Invalid syntax? This is beyond my knowledge to be honest.

Comment: Let me check deeply.

Comment: I think I found it, my json is 5 MB which is huge compared to what others use. So I simplified it with Mapshaper to 0,5 MB, problem solved. I did not realize that this level of detail is unnecessary.

Comment: Then, a memory problem? It sounds weird. Anyway, well done.

Answer (score 0):

Found that if the Json file is big, the jupyter canvas will not display the map. Once saved as HTML it displays nicely in the browser.